# Voting arrows don't line up

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The triangle voting images don't line up for me. Using Safari on Mac, they are two pixels different horizontally. Using Firefox on Mac, they are one pixel different.

Since the images are 40px wide, and the table cell that they are contained within is 60px wide, the following CSS should make everything all better:

```
.vote-up, .vote-down {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Edit: As Jeff pointed out, this solution doesn't work once the vote count forces its table cell to expand in width.

Here's an improved CSS solution that seems to work better:

```
.vote-up, .vote-down {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: <3 bug reports that include solutions.

Comment: How about a screenshot to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Two pixels different?  Jeff has some explaining to do.  This slapdash code is getting out of hand.

Comment: @Pesto: Agreed, time to fork some code!!!

Comment: Sure enough, I see the offset now that I look at it.  Thanks for setting off my OCD......

Comment: I didn't notice this until I read the question and really looked at it. Now I'm not going to be able to un-see it :(

Comment: The visual error doesn't appear to be caused through any fault of the current markup or CSS. Best as I can tell, the browsers just aren't lining things up right for whatever reason. This is just a workaround.

Comment: Just tilt your head *slightly* to the side... now its all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The downside to the fix, although appreciated, is that the arrows are now FIXED, which means double and triple digit votes look exceptionally bad. (try it yourself if you don't believe me)</s>

I agree that there's an offset (not sure why) in the bottom arrow; we need a css solution that lets them dynamically center.

Excellent. Thank you for this much needed CSS fix. That bugged me for a long time, too, but I had no idea what to do.

Deploying tonight!

Comment: You're right. I've updated the original question with an improved CSS solution.

Comment: It's not fixed for me. In fact, now even the voted arrows are off for me. Safari 4, Mac OS X Leopard.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing, Isaac.

Comment: No, now even on biztravel, SuperUser, FogBugz Knowledge Exchange... they all look like this: http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6391/arrows.tif Safari 4, Mac OS X Leopard...

Comment: It looked better before, now the arrows look __really__ sloppy.

Comment: Wow, you seem to have fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 3.5.2 on Windows: Bottom arrow one pixel to the left.

Damn that's going to annoy me now - curse you, aschall!

**Suggested workaround**: Upvote or downvote every question and answer you look at.  The arrows will be different sizes so you won't see the misalignment, and after about two and half minutes you'll run out of votes and have to go and do some work.

Comment: @downvoter: Nuts, I should have expected that.  8-)

Comment: I wanted to upvote you yesterday but I was out of vote.  But now **`+1`** for the joke!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 2.0.172.39 on Windows - Arrows don't line up

Comment: Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

You can really see it when it's blown up:
[bad upvote! http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/807/badupvote.tif](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/807/badupvote.tif)
It hurts my eyes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot - now I can't unsee it!

Answer (score 2):

There's a <br> tag between the down-arrow and the star. If you remove that, the arrows line up; but then the display is screwed up for large votes:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8042/votingarrowsdontlineupm.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8042/votingarrowsdontlineupm.png)

But if you add an additional <br> tag after the *up-arrow* instead of removing the other one, the arrows line up and everything looks fine.

**Edit:** When removing a typo in this answer, I had to answer this captcha:

[alt text http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/5956/hittingtags.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/5956/hittingtags.png)

Comment: Firebug cheater!

Comment: @John Smithers: Nope, good ol' text editor and a locally saved copy.

Comment: Don't say *Notepad*!

Comment: ...++          .

Comment: Phew! My worries were unfounded.

Comment: It does appear that the <br> element is indeed responsible. But since <img> elements are inline by default, it needs something to keep the next image from appearing on the same line.

Comment: @aschall: That's why I said "don't remove it, but add an additional one".

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br>` from under the down arrow, display the images as blocks and center using margin:0 auto. Remove the top margin of -5px from class favoritecount. Change the specificity for class vote-favorite and use a top margin instead of bottom.

```
.vote img {
   cursor:pointer;
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
}

.favoritecount {
   color:#808185;
   text-align:center;
}

img.vote-favorite {
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: This is the same as my improved solution, but with extra stuff. It's true that the <br> can be removed as it no longer serves any purpose after styling the arrows as display: block.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, now that this set off my OCD as well, I swear to God I'm seeing a pixel difference in FF3.5 on Windows. The bottom arrow is one pixel to the left of the top.

I'd never noticed it until it was pointed out ...

Comment: That's just the power of suggestion.  If I tell you that the commas actually appear to be completely beneath the baseline of the text, you'll think you can see that, too.

Comment: @Pesto: Oh sure, pick on the mentally ill. Real fair. They are victims of Apple's brainwashing, they can't help it!

Comment: I would say that, but I took a screen shot of Rich B's answer, dropped it in Paint.NET, magnified it to 600% and validated it by drawing a straight line up from the bottom arrow. Considered doing that in IE8, but I suspect it was just power of suggestion there.

Comment: @John: Well, to be fair, all of my posts are crooked and *evil*.

Comment: I can't tell if Rich B is joking or not. Must be the mental illness that goes with being cross-platform. :)

Comment: I see little commas underneath the number of views on the favorite cartoon question.  Oh wait, maybe those are "k"s.  Oh wait...

Comment: @John Rudy: **THE INTERNET IS SERIOUS BUSINESS**

Comment: @Rich B: Hold, I'll be right there. Someone is wrong on the internet! (Erm, oh, wait.)

Comment: Re the image answer I had before: Those who downvoted were correct; I deleted said answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.5.2 on Ubuntu. Arrows Line up!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.0.15 Mac -- arrows line up.